# Output mismatch While converting one time zone to another time zone

Tags: java, date

I try to convert date time zone to another time zone, I tried with the following code to convert, but it doesn't work.

I'm using JDK 1.3. My goal is to have the same time "Wed May  6 10:08:54 BST 2015" but with a different timezone stamp. So my expected output is: "Wed May  6 10:08:54 IST 2015". I don't want to calculate the difference.

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
              Test obj= new Test();
              String date="Wed May  6 10:08:54 BST 2015";
            System.out.println("Given Date = "+date);
            Date dt=obj.getServerDate(date);
            System.out.println("Returned Date = "+dt);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public Date getServerDate(String str_date)
    {
        if (str_date == null)
            return null;
        Date pars_date = null;
        try
        {
            DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            pars_date = sdf.parse(str_date); 
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return pars_date;
}
```

When I execute the above code I got the following output:

```
Given Date = Wed May  6 10:08:54 BST 2015
Returned Date = Wed May 06 14:38:54 IST 2015
```

The returned date is mismatched, I tried lot to solve this problem, but I couldn't. Share your ideas to solve this problem.

**Note: I don't want Joda Time calendar**
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you expecting? How is it wrong?

Comment: Which Java Version are you using? Date handling changed in Java8.

Comment: You said the returned time is correct. I'm expecting output like **Wed May  6 10:08:54 IST 2015** @Brett Walker

Comment: Wed May  6 10:08:54 BST 2015 is Wed May 06 14:38:54 IST 2015. I can't see the problem here. You want to take a time in BST and make it the SAME time and date but in IST?

Comment: I'm using **JDK 1.3** @Angelo Fuchs

Comment: @KaviChinna Please note: don't provide additional information in comments; update the content of your question instead.

Comment: @KaviChinna Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873119/changing-timezone-without-changing-time-in-java The solution is to basically rebuild the data from the original date objects but inject your own timezone. Trying to convert the object will also affect the rest of the time/date.

Comment: on another node: the "setTimeZone" method call in your code does nothing. It just happens to work because your computer runs in IST. On my machine it produces MESZ.

Answer (score 1):

Your returned time is correct **BST** is [+1:00](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london) and **IST** is [+5:30](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/india/new-delhi) so when it is *10:08:54* in London it is *14:38:54* in New Delhi.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the timezone without changing the time/date and don't want to use Joda you'll need to first parse the string to a date object, then rebuild a NEW date object using values from the old one but inject your own timezone. Changing the timezone on the date formatter will also change the time/date.

P.s. See [Changing timezone without changing time in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873119/changing-timezone-without-changing-time-in-java)